# Can I use Gerrit code review with an existing Git repository?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a git server that I use to clone my sources locally via ssh.
I want to use Gerrit server I have installed, but only for code review.
I mean - changes are done on "regular" git repository, and Gerrit used for code review only, without permissions, pull, push etc.
The review can be done after submit too if possible.

Is there a setup like this or I'm crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not impossible, it's highly recommended that you do not use Gerrit this way. The way Gerrit works the changes/reviews, the patchsets, the rework process, etc are very different when using Gerrit. If you want to use Gerrit for code review (this is really a great choice) then it's better to migrate your repository to Gerrit server. The migration process is very simple and you can migrate back any time you want if you wish.

See more info about the Gerrit process [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-gerrit-walkthrough.html).

Comment: If it's not impossible, can you elaborate?